# Convertir cadena a código php

Tags: php, array, base-de-datos, string

Quiero convertir o ejecutar una cadena de base de datos a `php`,
mi consulta me devuelve

```
array("datos_correo_entrada"=>array("emisor"=>"ejemplo@ejemplo.com", "contrasenia"=>"=1454", "destinatarios"=>"soldeir@gmail.com", "asunto"=>"sdsdsdsd", "cuerpo"=>"sdsddsd"))
```

y quiero que una variable tenga ese arreglo y quede como el siguiente código:

```
$datos_correo_entrada = array("datos_correo_entrada"=>array("emisor"=>"ejemplo@ejemplo.com", "contrasenia"=>"=1454", "destinatarios"=>"soldier@gmail.com", "asunto"=>"sdsdsdsd", "cuerpo"=>"sdsddsd"));
```

intente utilizar la funcion `eval();` y darle el valor a la variale pero no funciona.

```
$datos_correo_entrada = array($dataCo->correo);
```

Comment: No se entiende lo que tratas de hacer

Comment: Uff. Deberías plantearte que la BBDD guarde datos serializado (como json) y luego tratar ese serializado. Guardar cosas como la que tienes te va a traer más problemas y disgustos que beneficios... Puedes poner el código que has utilizado de eval? En tu ejemplo no aparece

Comment: De base de datos me trae una cadena en, esa cadena tiene forma de arreglo, pero al tratar de ejecutar ese codigo en php no me funciona, esa cadena la asigno a una variable he intento recorrerla pero no la toma como arreglo si no como string

Comment: pues sería interesante que muestres como intentas recorrer dichos datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se podría realizar de esta manera,

```
     $cadena='array("datos_correo_entrada"=>array("emisor"=>"ejemplo@ejemplo.com", "contrasenia"=>"=1454", "destinatarios"=>"soldeir@gmail.com", "asunto"=>"sdsdsdsd", "cuerpo"=>"sdsddsd"))';
     $busqueda=array(
        'array(',
        '=>',
        ')'
     );
     $reemplazo=array(
        '{',
        ':',
        '}',
     );
     /*
     Se reemplazan correspondientemente los caracteres de 
     $busqueda por los de $reemplazo.
     Con esto se pasa a una estructura JSON para utilizar
     las funciones de php que perimiten manipularlos.
     */
     $strJson=str_replace( $busqueda,$reemplazo, $cadena);
     echo($strJson);
     //Pasamos el JSON a un arreglo asociativo
     $arregloDatos=json_decode($strJson, true);
     var_dump($arregloDatos);
```

Pero no va a funcionar si en la estructura se encuentra un indice que sea un arreglo, algo como:

```
array( "nom"=>"kk", "arreglo_numeros"=>array(1,2,3,4), "arreglo_de_arreglos"=>array(array("llave"=>"valor"), array("llave"=>"valor")))
```

Por tanto sería mejor que la base de datos entregara el contenido de una mejor manera, como en un string en formato JSON.